# url rewrite .htaccess - Once redirected to a folder, redirects all pages to this folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using rewrite rules in the .htaccess file like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule start$ index.php?content=start
RewriteRule folder/name$ index.php?content=name
```

The problem is, once i opened the site 'folder/name', and want to go back to 'start', it doesn't go up one folder and the displayed url is 'folder/start'.

Why is that?

I know i should use regex, but this would be too time intesive for me to solve, as the rules would be quite complicated and i don't have the time to get into regex at this point. 
I need to solve it with single 'RewriteRule' statements.

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks @anubahva !